# Slow UPDATE queries after migrate to new server

Tags: php, mysql, debian, innodb

I have moved my website to new faster dedicated server (64GB RAM, CPU 4c/8t 3.7GHz in OVH). The problem is that now my site works even slower, not faster.

I figured out that this is because of slow UPDATE queries to my mysql. I have read many topics, tried many configurations without any luck. Mysql config is almost default so I don't understand why it is not working. This is not overload because I turned off website and make test from phpmyadmin - same results.

So I have this query in phpmyadmin and execute this few times on both server. Tables (InnoDB) and data are exactly the same.

```
UPDATE `user` SET `last_date` = "2017-02-05 03:40:50" WHERE `id`=3;
```

Times on new server:

```
 0.0553 s
 0.0265 s
 0.0229 s
 0.0369 s
 0.1579 s <---
 0.0191 s
```

Times on old server:

```
 0.0024 s
 0.0042 s
 0.0015 s
 0.0015 s
 0.0015 s
 0.0012 s
```

New server software: Debian 8, Mysql 5.5.31, Apache 2.2.16, PHP 7.1

Old server software: Debian 6, Mysql 5.5.31, Apache 2.2.16, PHP 5.3

**I've tried copy entire my.cnf from old to new but results are the same. So why the same config works great on old system, but not on new fresh one?**

New server my.cnf

```
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 0
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 0
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
slow_query_log      = 1
long_query_time = 2
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16G
max_connections = 2048
skip_name_resolve = 1
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
key_buffer      = 16M
```

Old server my.cnf

```
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /dev/shm
bind-address        = 0.0.0.0
key_buffer      = 128M
max_allowed_packet  = 40M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 1000
table_cache            = 4096
thread_concurrency     = 10
max_heap_table_size = 48M
tmp_table_size      = 48M
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 2
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4500M
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
key_buffer      = 16M
```

Why is this happening?

**Edit:** 
I have tried also:

1. Make query directly from mysql terminal.
2. Restart apache after my.cnf change.
3. PHP 5.

Comment: Have you run this consistently and seen the problem?  An occasional hiccup can be caused by many factors . . . other processes on the server, an update, network congestions, etc.

Comment: do you have restarted your apache server after moving cfg file from old system to new? tried to run your new server with php 5?

Comment: Try your query without any other application direct in the mysql client to see if there is a difference in execution time.

Comment: are you sure  you don't miss some index ..   and looking to your query seems that you have the id as a string  .. this is true?  or is a  number?

Comment: I have restart apache after my.cnf change - the same. Also I do not have wrong index etc, because this is 1:1 same database. After change id from string to int it works the same. Even if this was wring query, why is this works perfectly on old server? Problem is 24/7, server load is not a cause, like I said, i even turned off website and was only one using database - same results. Network - its 1gbps. I also tested execution time directly in php script with update, same problem with lags.

Comment: I have also run this query from terminal - same problem.

Comment: PHP 5 - same problem.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE user`